# Are there any Neo-Latin Sci-Fi or Cyberpunk (original or translation)?

Tags: new-latin, literature-request

Salvete omnes!

I was wondering if anybody knew of any Neo-Latin original sci-fi or cyberpunk story. If not, are there any good translations for modern sci-fi or cyberpunk classics in Latin? If you know of any, could you comment on the quality of the translation?

Comment: I do kinda want a Latin edition of _Neuromancer_ now. Maybe once generative AI has improved a bit...